# How can I read from a stream without waiting for newline?

Tags: c, console, posix, pipe

I'm trying to write a simple console program in C that forks, runs a child process and, with pipe(), reads all stdin of the parent program and sends it to the stdin of the child program and reads all stdout of the child program and sends it to the stdout of the parent program.  Eventually, I can make the parent do something other than just passing this data through—for now, it would suffice if the parent program behaves as if the child program were run directly.

Seems to work fine, except that when I read() from the stream that is piped from the child's output it won't return anything until a newline is encountered.  This means that if the child process asks a question in middle of a line, the question will never appear until after the user types the answer, which is unacceptable.

I also have the same problem with the parent's stdin.  Even if the user should be able to answer the question with a simple "y", the program cannot read the "y" until the user pushes enter, which is also unacceptable.

I'm setting the input stream to nonblocking with:

```
fcntl(stream, F_SETFL, fcntl(stream, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
```

It works fine, but read() returns -1 until a newline is encountered.

Is there something I can do to read the actual data from the streams without being "protected" from partial lines?  Or is there some totally different approach I should take?  Is there some open source program that does something similar that I can examine?

Code is here:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
    int outfd[2];
    int infd[2];

    int oldstdin, oldstdout;

    pipe2(outfd, O_NONBLOCK); // Where the parent is going to write to
    pipe2(infd, O_NONBLOCK); // From where parent is going to read

    oldstdin = dup(0); // Save current stdin
    oldstdout = dup(1); // Save stdout

    close(0);
    close(1);

    dup2(outfd[0], 0); // Make the read end of outfd pipe as stdin
    dup2(infd[1],1); // Make the write end of infd as stdout

    if(!fork())
    {
        const char * pChildArguments[] = { "/usr/bin/php", "test.php", 0 };
        close(outfd[0]); // Not required for the child
        close(outfd[1]);
        close(infd[0]);
        close(infd[1]);

        execv(pChildArguments[0], (char * const *)pChildArguments);
    }
    else
    {
        char input[100];
        close(0); // Restore the original std fds of parent
        close(1);
        dup2(oldstdin, 0);
        dup2(oldstdout, 1);

        close(outfd[0]); // These are being used by the child
        close(infd[1]);

        fcntl(infd[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(infd[0], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
        fcntl(0, F_SETFL, fcntl(0, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

        for (;;) {
            ssize_t readReturnValue;

            readReturnValue = read(infd[0], input, 100);
            if (readReturnValue == 0) { break; }
            if (readReturnValue > 0) {
                write(1, input, readReturnValue);
                fsync(1);
            }
            readReturnValue = read(0, input, 100);
            if (readReturnValue > 0) {
                write(outfd[1], input, readReturnValue);
                fsync(outfd[1]);
            }
            sched_yield();
        }
    }
}
```

It was adapted from [this blog post](http://jineshkj.wordpress.com/2006/12/22/how-to-capture-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-of-child-program/).

The test.php (used as a child process) is this:

```
<?php
echo "This lines goes through.\n";
$a = readline("Say something: ");
echo "You said " . $a . "\n";
```

Comment: Does your child call fflush for the pipe?

Comment: Are you sure it's the receiving process that is wrong, and it's not the sender that wait for a newline before sending? Can you please edit your question to include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: I have no control over how the child process is programmed, except in the simple test case above.  This parent should work for any child program and it should appear to behave the same as the child behaves when it is run directly.  If a question is correctly output when the child is run directly, it should be correctly output when the parent runs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason nothing works properly is that `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` don't characterize the entire input and output of the child program.  Instead, we are more interested in the TTY that is attached to the child process.  The proper way to implement this sort of program is with [`forkpty()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/login_tty.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Now when I see your whole code, there's some problems with it.

The first (and not really a problem) is that you don't have to close the descriptors before calling `dup2`, as `dup2` will close them for you.

The second, is that you really don't need to do any descriptor duplication *before* the fork. you can do all that after the fork. speaking of this, when you do your first duplications of the standard in and out, that's not needed as in the parent process you then use those duplicates to *reset* the standard in and out back to the originals.

You also don't check for errors from some functions (`dup`, `dup2`, `fork` and others). This includes things like handling `EWOULDBLOCK` like `read` most often would return with.

You also set the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on `infd[0]` twice, once in the `pipe2` call, the other manually in the parent.

The use of `fsync` with pipes and the standard output is also not needed. It's mostly used for files open on slow device
s where the system caches data to speed up the write calls. While the console output can be considered a slow device, it's still not cached in the way like disk writes are, and writing to standard output using file descriptors is unbuffered. Pipes are buffered, but there is still nothing to synchronize as the buffer is just so that one process can write at one end and another process can read at another.

And now to what the real problem *probably* is: The console. To be able to handle things like editing, cursor movement etc., it's the *terminal emulator application* that buffers the input and doesn't give it to your process until the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. You have to use [termios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface) functionality to disable that. See [for example here](http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html) for a very simple example on how to disable CANONICAL mode (which disables line-buffered mode)

---

As for your program, the typical way of writing a program such as yours would be more something like this:

```
int pipes1[2], pipes2[2];

pipe(pipes1);
pipe(pipes2);

int res = fork();
if (res == -1)
    perror("fork");
else if (res == 0)
{
    dup2(pipes1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(pipes2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    close(pipes1[1]);
    close(pipes2[0]);

    exec(...);
}
else
{
    close(pipes1[0]);
    close(pipes2[1]);

    /* Read from `pipes2[0]`, write to `pipes1[1]` */
}
```

Less and simpler code I would think.

Comment: When I run the php script directly, I see the _question_ immediately.  But when I run it as a child of the C program, the _question_ does not appear.  This is the real problem.  Besides, I don't care if the _child_ is blocking until it gets a full line.  The child can block all it wants.  As long as the parent sends the input characters to the child as soon as they are available.

Comment: @user2634914 Now when I see your code, it's easy to figure out what you're doing, and what the problem is. I completely rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I needed to get the status flags (with `fcntl`) of the streams 0 and 1 and set those same flags on the pipe endpoints that are used in place of the real streams 0 and 1.  The `readline()` prompt from PHP still doesn't show up, but it's not that it doesn't show up until the user enters something, it's that it just doesn't show up at all, which is weird.  But my little program works very well with ffmpeg (which prompts you if you want to overwrite a file), so I think it's good enough for my purposes.  My thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: Some programs will display interactive prompts on `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Check for that.